# Adding rich text editors dynamically in HTML/JavaScript (subsequent instances produce text areas instead)

Tags: javascript, html, flask, ckeditor

I have a flask web application and I'm trying to add rich text editors dynamically in the HTML template. However, only the first field is a rich text editor, the others appear as textareas.

Here is the first rich text editor box with a button to add a new one and a button to remove one (HTML):

```
<div class='f_elements'>
  <div id='inputFormFormalElements'>
    <textarea name="f_element[]" id="f_element[]" class="ckeditor"></textarea>
    <button id="removeFormalElement" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
  </div>
                    
  <div id="newFormalElement"></div>
  <button id="addFormalElement" type='button' class="btn btn-info">Add a slot</button>
</div>
```

**Edit**: Here is the script to dynamically add new fields:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#addFormalElement', function(){
        $("#newFormalElement").append('<div id="inputFormFormalElements"><textarea name="f_element[]" id="f_element[]" class="ckeditor"></textarea><button id="removeFormalElement" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>');
        CKEDITOR.replaceAll('ckeditor');
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#removeFormalElement", function(){
        $(this).closest('#inputFormFormalElements').remove();
    });
```

**Edit**: Now the problem is that when I click the button (to add a new field), the second editor is added just normally, but when I try to add the third field and further subsequent fields, the first two fields become suddenly merged (no break between them).[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, after I added two more fields to the original one, I got 2 merged fields + break + another 2 merged fields + break + and another field (5 fields in total). The expected behaviour would be getting 3 fields in total with break between them.

I would be grateful if somebody could point out what I'm doing wrong.

Note: It's okay that the dynamically added elements have the same id. I would then collect all input under the same key as a list in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution!

Apparently the conflict was caused by the fact that the newly added text editor boxes have the same ids, and the ckeditor does not allow that. So, the only thing I changed is that I am now dynamically updating the id of the added ckeditor box.

Now everything works perfectly!

```
    // add formal elements
    let i = 1;
    $(document).on('click', '#addFormalElement', function(){
        $("#newFormalElement").append('<div id="inputFormFormalElements"><textarea name="f_element[]" id="f_element[]' + i + '" class="ckeditor"></textarea><button id="removeFormalElement" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>');
        CKEDITOR.replace('f_element[]' + i);
        i++
    });

    // remove formal elements
    $(document).on("click", "#removeFormalElement", function(){
        $(this).closest('#inputFormFormalElements').remove();
    });
```